# How to get my Cassandra DB to represent my Keys and Values as UTF8?

Tags: utf-8, cassandra, hector

I am new to Cassandra, and have been playing around with the Hector API. As you can see in the screenshot below, I Have a Column Family defined and when i use CQL to return the rows, it is returning the Key and Value as a Hex Value, I would like to return it as a UTF8 value if possible. Also, it seems my My Column Name did not take, it is using "Column1" instead. I'll post my col family declaration below.

```
//Define ColumnFamily Def in Hector
            ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(keyspaceName,"DP_ColumnFamily1",ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);      


            //Add the column family to actual Cassandra Instance
            cluster.addColumnFamily(cfDef,false);

            stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();

             //The following example inserts a Column with the column name "Datapower_Device_Name" and the column value of "DPIPE0101" under the key "key1". 

            Mutator mutator = HFactory.createMutator(ksp, stringSerializer);
            mutator.insert("key1", "DP_ColumnFamily1", HFactory.createStringColumn("Datapower_Device_Name", "DPIPE0101"));


cqlsh:test3> select * from "DP_ColumnFamily1";

 key        | column1               | value
------------+-----------------------+----------------------
 0x6b657931 | Datapower_Device_Name | 0x445049504530313031

(1 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(keyspaceName,"DP_ColumnFamily1",ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);
```

creates a column family with the *comparator* set to UTF8.  The comparator defines the data type of your column *names*, and says nothing about the values.  CQL is smart enough to use this comparator to correctly display the name as a string when you run your query, but it has no information at all about the key or value types.

A better approach would be to use the new [native driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver), which avoids Thrift altogether and allows you to do everything via CQL.  Then you'd be able to create your schema in CQL like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Device (
  DeviceID varchar, 
  DeviceName varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (DeviceID)
);
```

... then insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO Device (DeviceID, DeviceName) 
VALUES ('Some_ID', 'DPIPE0101');
```

then if you query in `cqlsh` it looks like this:

```
 deviceid | devicename
----------+------------
  Some_ID |  DPIPE0101
```

Keep in mind that CQL rows are not a direct correlation to storage rows, so you shouldn't really mix Thrift and CQL-based operations.  The exception is that it's helpful to use `cassandra-cli` to see what the storage engine is doing with your CQL.  In this case it looks like this:

```
RowKey: Some_ID
=> (name=, value=, timestamp=1382118992099000)
=> (name=devicename, value=445049504530313031, timestamp=1382118992099000)
```